# Windows 8 NetScheduleJobAdd The request is not supported

Tags: windows, task, jobs, schedule

Application uses API functions like: NetScheduleJobAdd, NetScheduleJobEnum, NetScheduleJobGetInfo. 
Looks like those functions do not work with Windows 8 Jobs. 
On creating new job getting error: "The request is not supported" (error ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
AT.exe also does not work in Windows 8. Display the same error.

Documentation quite poor about AT command and Windows 8.
Can somebody explain why mentioned above functions do not work in Windows 8. 
Is there any other approaches?
Maybe it is connected with changes in Task Scheduler Architecture in Windows 8?

Comment: It appears you need to set a registry key to enable the task scheduler on Windows 8.  See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/e0e31d5e-a8e3-4864-a186-86063cd5473c/win32scheduledjob-windows-8?forum=ITCG

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for Win32_ScheduledJob](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa394399%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) says:

> The Win32_ScheduledJob class is internally using the AT protocol, which is bound to deprecation starting with Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012. As a first step the AT protocol is disabled by default.

To turn the protocol back on, add the following registry entry:

```
Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Configuration  
Name: EnableAt  
Type: REG_DWORD 
Value: 1
```